# How to use system's colors in a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib with wxpython. My problem is that the facecolor in the figure is darker than out of it. [image: the color in the figure is darker than out of it]

What is the name of the system's color? to put it in

```
fig = pl.figure( facecolor = System_color)
```